# Readfiles in a while loop in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading all the json files in the directory and performing CRUD operations on them in Couchbase in a cyclic manner for some performance benchmarks.

```
function readFiles(dirName,crudOps, onError){
    fs.readdir(dirName,function(err,filenames){
     if (err) {
        onError(err);
        return;
      }
    var circularIterator = cyclicIterator(filenames);


    while(1){
     fname = circularIterator.next().value;

      fs.readFile(dirName + fname, function(err, content) {
          console.log(fname) // NEVER REACHES HERE
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
          }
          crudOps(fname, content);
        });
    });
    }
 })

}
```

However, it does not seem to be executing the `fs.readFile` function. How can I make it 'circular' iterate through the list of filenames and use the file content for my `crudOps` function?

EDIT:

Per the suggestion by Ry, I have used a promise to readFile.

```
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

async function getStuff(filename) {
  return await readFile(filename);

}

function readFiles(dirName,onFileContent, onError){
    fs.readdir(dirName,function(err,filenames){
     if (err) {
        onError(err);
        return;
      }
    var iterator = circularIterator(filenames);

    //filenames.forEach(function(filename) {
    while(1){
        fname = iterator.next().value;
    //iterator.getNext(function(filename){
    //
        getStuff(dirName + fname).then(data => {console.log(data); onFileContent(fname, data)})

    }
 })

}
```

This is hanging and causing my Chrome browser to crash and with the below error on my console:

**FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory**

Is there a way to make this better?

Comment: `fs.readFile` is asynchronous, so it enqueues a task and moves to the next iteration of the loop. The loop runs forever, so infinite tasks get enqueued and they never run. You’ll need to use one of the usual ways to wait for the `fs.readFile` before continuing with the loop, like an async function and a promise wrapper for `fs.readFile`.

Comment: HI Ry, I have made the improvements per your suggestion, but I am running into a heap space issue. Please see edits on original post.

Comment: Your loop still doesn’t wait for anything. The `await` would have to be directly inside it.

Comment: I don't understand. Like how?

Comment: Chrome browser to crash when you run your node app?

Comment: @user2405589: Delete `getStuff` and put `await readFile(…)` inside the loop. Make the callback to `fs.readdir` an `async function` for now.

Comment: I did not test my answer, it was actually wrong. Updated my answer with a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have limitless amounts of file reads, you can find the maximum your computer can handle and limit the program to that.

To limit activity you can recursively call a function that will (if not maximum active processes are started) read file and do stuff with it and if it's finished then do it again.

```
function readFiles(dirName, onFileContent, onError) {
  fs.readdir(dirName, function (err, filenames) {
    if (err) {
      onError(err);
      return;
    }
    const recur = (iterator) => {
      const fname = iterator.next().value;
      getStuff(dirName + fname)
      .then(
        data => { 
          console.log(data);
          //if the following is an asynchronous function then
          //  you should wait for it to finish before calling recur
          onFileContent(fname, data);
          //recursively call itself
          recur(iterator);
        }
      );
    };
    const iterator = circularIterator(filenames);
    var i = 0;
    while(i++<1000){//maximum amount of active tasks
      recur(iterator);
    }
  })
}
```

Working example:

```js
var later = time => value =>
  new Promise(
    (resolve,reject)=>
      setTimeout(
        ()=>resolve(value),
        time
      )
  )
;
var waitTwoSeconds = later(2000);
function *myIterator(){
  var i = 1;
  while(i<=15){
    yield i++;
  }
}

function readFiles() {
  const recur = (iterator) => {
    const value = iterator.next().value;
    if(value===undefined){
      console.log("----- Done")
      return;
    }
    waitTwoSeconds(value)
    .then(
      data => { 
        console.log("returned",data);
        recur(iterator);
      }
    );
  };
  const iterator = myIterator();
    var i = 0;
    while(i++<5){
      recur(iterator);
    }
}
readFiles();
```